# jQuery toggleClass animation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this page:

http://beta.amitai-clinic.com/

If you hover the top left logo, it should 'fade' the same logo with some text underneath it.

Problem is, the logo part is being faded in naturally, but the text beneath it looks like it's being placed in all together, and not faded in 'naturally'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw, your text is written over the image, having a different background on mouseover and I think the problems are caused by that

You could try instead to do something like this:

```
<div class="sublogo-stress" style=" ">
    <img src="/wp-content/themes/SimplePress/images/trans_120x90.png">
    <span>test</span>
</div>
```

You could even set the opacity of span to 0 to make it completely invisible.
The fade effect should work better now.

Answer (score 0):

toggleClass changes opacity to match the opacity of the hover class and than adds the class. but, anyway, the point where you change the class will behave as a sudden appearance of the text. Look here http://jsfiddle.net/eYJym/

You can 'bypass' this effect by fading to 0 where the class should be toggled. Or by placing the invisible layer with the text above the original image, fade it to some opacity and then hide the layer with the original image. It will be much easier to deal with images without transparency :)